# Joomla Content Editor 2.4 how to configure font sizes option

Tags: joomla, configuration, tinymce

JCE recently gets updated to ver 2.4.2. When trying the new version, I realized that the option to change the editor font sizes is missing.

Usually I can find the option (on JCE ver 2.3.4.4) at `Components -> JCE Editor -> Profiles -> Default -> Editor Parameters -> Typography`

But now that the setting is gone. The setting to configure the available fonts is also gone. I looked everywhere for the options but finds nothing. Also I tried putting this in the editor's `Global Configuration -> Advanced -> Custom Configuration Variables`

```
font_size_style_values: "8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 26px 36px"
```

Or

```
fontsize_formats: "8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 26px 36px"
```

I still can't change the font sizes on the editor. Does anyone know how to change font sizes in JCE 2.4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found it in `Components -> JCE Editor -> Profiles -> Default -> Plugin Parameters -> Font Size Select` (about the 7th item down on the left tabs.

It looks like this:
[image: JCE Font Size Select Options]

Comment: wasn't here in the previous version. Thanks btw